# Twitter-Bootstrap affix

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying the affix feature on twitter-bootstrap, what this js method does, cause as i see it just puts the element choosed to:

`position:fixed;`

Or i'm mistaking and it also controls the element `window offsets TOP,BOTTOM,LEFT,RIGHT ..` ?

The main method i'm referring to is the :

```
$('.element').affix();
```

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12577809/451969

Comment: not "trying to build up afflix behavior" sorry, anyway thanks

Comment: @ic3b3rg i know how to use it read my question pls

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels ops , right :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of the use of affix is the menu in the [bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html).

At the top of the place the menu is just on it's normal position. However if you scroll down, the position of the menu changes so it stays on screen.

You might need to set top for a specific element in CSS.

```
.bs-docs-sidenav.affix {
  top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: ok, so left and right are calculated via affix method? cause my div is moving on the left when affixed, so i'm wondering if to create a jqury method to make it fixed in the same place.

Comment: No, left and right shouldn't change. Check what's happening using firebug or equivalent.

Comment: Regarding your div moving left when affixed. I'm seeing similar behavior with my project right now. I think the div is recalculating the width based on the content of the element. So when .affix-top is applied the div is constrained to its column. But when .affix is applied the div is no longer constrained, and therefore it gets wider.