# Bootstrap beginner problems

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making my first bootstrap website and having a bunch of problems.

[The site is live here](http://www.posterlikes.com/page/)

1. Used bootstrap build-in feature "navbar-fixed-top", which have messed up the nav position. How can i get it into place again. *(if you uncheck "position:fixed" with ff you can see where the nav should be)*
2. I have added two carousels. I get some numbers instead of the nice circle pagination. Why is that ?
3. When i resize the browser my background-color does not expand 100% i get like 10px whitespace on each side.

Comment: I assume you're utilizing the [Bootstrap Boilerplate](http://www.initializr.com/)? [Also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12577809/451969).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of using `navbar-fixed-top` try using `affix span12`
2. I don't see the `carousel-indicators` class in your bootstrap.css. Make sure you have the latest version.
3. I'm not having this problem.

Comment: Affix span12 worked perfect. What does it do ? I updated bootstrap css this also made the slider work. Many thanks

Comment: `span12` makes the element the width of the entire grid. `affix` makes the element stay put when you scroll. `navbar-fixed-top` makes the element the width of the screen, rather than just the container.

Comment: Makes great sense. Thanks alot for your help